# Hera 5.1.7 - Display Slowdown After Connecting CRT via Adapter. (Persisting After CRT Disconnect and Restart)

Tags: display, pantheon, xorg

Recently I was playing with some CRTs hooked up to my computer via a simple VGA-to-DVI-D adapter. Some monitors worked, but there were a few with weird refresh issues that would cause slowdown on eOS as the CRT kept restarting, attempting to correct itself.

On Windows, there was no slowdown persisting after I plugged my computer back into my normal ViewSonic 60hz LCD monitor via DisplayPort. eOS is having a bad time, however.

Pantheon is scaling correctly, but only seems to be refreshing about once every three seconds. I tried restarting the x-server and disconnecting and reconnecting my monitor but the issue is still persisting.

My specs are
i7-6700K
RX 580
16GB RAM

Any help troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While I was playing with the CRTs I enabled the iGPU on my CPU to see if the display would work that way.

I plugged an HDMI cable into the Motherboard's port and my main monitor started working immediately.

I rebooted into the bios and disabled the iGPU and now everything is running correctly.